# mystyfing unit tests failing

Tags: sql-server-2005, nhibernate, nunit-2.5

We are using NHIbernate, .net and sql server2005.  What is mystyfing most is that using **the same database, the same unit tests,** my friends are not having any kind of messages and all their tests are passing, whereas with mine i`m having error messages:

```
ERROR [TestRunnerThread] ADOExceptionReporter [(null)]- The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_Project_Client". The conflict occurred in database "TestDev", table "dbo.Project", column 'ClientID'. The statement has been terminated. 13:10:02,656 ERROR [TestRunnerThread] SessionImpl [(null)]- could not synchronize database state with session NHibernate.ADOException: could not delete: [Client#875][SQL: DELETE FROM Client WHERE ID = ?] ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_Project_Client". The conflict occurred in database "TestDev", table "dbo.Project", column 'ClientID'.
```

> > at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException
> >     exception, Boolean breakConnection)
>
> at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection)
>
> at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
>
> at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior
>   runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler,
>   SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet
>   bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj)
>
> at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader
>   ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String
>   resetOptionsString)
>
> at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
>
> at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   Boolean returnStream, String method,
>   DbAsyncResult result)
>
> at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult
>   result, String methodName, Boolean
>   sendToPipe)
>
> at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>
> at
>   NHibernate.Impl.BatcherImpl.ExecuteNonQuery(IDbCommand
>   cmd)
>
> at
>   NHibernate.Impl.NonBatchingBatcher.AddToBatch(IExpectation
>   expectation)
>
> at
>   NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Delete(Object
>   id, Object version, Int32 j, Object
>   obj, SqlCommandInfo sql,
>   ISessionImplementor session, Object[]
>   loadedState)
>
> --- End of inner exception stack
>   trace ---
>
> at
>   NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Delete(Object
>   id, Object version, Int32 j, Object
>   obj, SqlCommandInfo sql,
>   ISessionImplementor session, Object[]
>   loadedState)
>
> at
>   NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Delete(Object
>   id, Object version, Object obj,
>   ISessionImplementor session)
>
> at
>   NHibernate.Impl.ScheduledDeletion.Execute()
>
> at
>   NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Execute(IExecutable
>   executable)
>
> at
>   NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.ExecuteAll(IList
>   list)
>
> at
>   NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Execute()
>
> The statement has been terminated.
>   Like the above, I am having various other tests failing with the error messages
>
> could not synchronize database state
>   with session

Any idea whay I am having the error messages, does anyone know?

Answer (score 2):

Are all tests mutually exclusive? That is they all run `independently` of each other It may be that 1 test is interfering with another test.

If you run the test by itself do you get the same problem?

Also are you running the test on your own dev database or is it a shared dev database? If it is your own then is the `data` exactly the same as your colleagues?

I know this is not strictly an answer and has lots of questions, but hopefully one of these questions will lead you to the solution.

Comment: Agreed.  It sounds like tests are not cleaning up after themselves and/or possibly the test database and the tests are not in fact in sync after all.  Take a test that is failing consistently, then rebuild the latest database completely from scratch and run that test by itself.